# Tensors - The Divergence formula for a given metric tensor.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, tensors, divergence-operator

I'm trying to determine the equation of divergence for the given metric

$$ g_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}
    u^2+v^2 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & u^2+v^2 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 &  u^2v^2 
  \end{bmatrix} $$

Which is the metric for a paraboloidal space.

The divergence of some vector, given in my textbook, is

$$ \nabla_{i}V^{i} = \partial_{i}V^{i} + \Gamma^{i}_{i j}V^{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i(\sqrt{|g|}\ V^{i}  ) 
 $$

Where $g = \det{g_{ij}}$

If I where to work it out, how would some parts in the derivative cancel out with the inverse determinant? I tried this formula to determine the divergence in spherical coordinates, but I also run into the same problem to how I cancel coefficients.